# Clear memory cache using Crontab

Tags: 16.04, cron, ram

I'm trying to clear memory cache using cron.

Cron file:

```
*/2 * * * *  ~/clear_mem.sh
```

clear_mem.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
touch f
```

File `f` is created every two minutes. But memory isn't cleared. If I call script by hands everything is fine. Why?

Comment: This begs the question... why are you trying to clear memory cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `cron` runs commands non-interactively, there is no way for `sudo` to authenticate.

For commands that require root permission, you should use root's crontab (i.e. `sudo crontab -e` instead of plain `crontab -e`) and then avoid the use of `sudo` within your commands and scripts altogether.

You should also give the full path to the script - preferably locate it some systemwide e.g. `/usr/local/bin/clear_mem.sh` in place of `~/clear_mem.sh`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal and type crontab -e to edit the cron jobs.
2. If you're prompted to choose an editor, select your preferred editor.
3. Add the following line at the end of the file:

   ```
   */5 * * * * /usr/bin/sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   ```

This cron job will run every five minutes and execute the command to clear the memory cache. The command will first flush the data in the system buffers to disk using sync, then it will write 1 to the `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` file, which tells the kernel to drop the page cache, dentries, and inodes.

Comment: No where did the OP ask about running the command over and over, it seems for ever.